# How best to change the font size (etc) of threeparttable's table notes?

Tags: tables, fontsize, threeparttable

How best to change the font size (etc) of the **`threeparttable`** table notes ?

Google returned these (duplicate) unanswered stubs (in English and German, but with pictures ;)

- http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/changing-font-size-of-table-notes-in-threepartt/1916286
- http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=72470
- http://www.golatex.de/threeparttable-legende-t8060.html

I tried `\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\small\linespread{1}}`, and surely enough: the result looks like in the screenshots of the above links.

[Elsewhere](http://blackwing.de/files/tex/thesis/thesis.tex) I spotted `\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\small\linespread{1}\selectfont}`, though I'm not sure what the `\selectfont` part does: what does it do?

**Edit**

To add [another link](http://www.44342.com/tex-f809-t9531-p1.htm) (which I had already opened but overlooked):

> Re: threeparttable: multicolumn table notes
>
> Postby Bil Kleb » Sat, 10 Apr 2004 16:37:35 GMT
>
> Arseneau assisted me offline.  The conclusion: the whole idea of the
>   \tablenotes list environment is set to be 'tablewidth' wide. 
>   Therefore, merely make your own list that inherits the existing
>   \linewidth set by the multicols environment.  A lame example:
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
>    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
>    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
>    \newcommand{\mcmakelabel}[1]{\textsuperscript#1}
>    \newenvironment{mctablenotes}%
>     {\begin{footnotesize}\begin{list}{}{\topsep 0pt \partopsep  0pt
>      \setlength\itemsep{4pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} \leftmargin 0pt
>      \parsep 0pt \itemindent 0pt \labelsep 0pt \raggedright}%
>      \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textsuperscript 1}%
>      \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\mcmakelabel}}%
>     {\end{list}\end{footnotesize}}%
>
>    \begin{multicols}{2}
>     \begin{mctablenotes}
>      \item[1] Also known as code-n-fix.
>      \item[2] For teams of ``code monkeys''
>     \end{mctablenotes}
>    \end{multicols}
> ```
>
> --  enter code hereBil Kleb, Hampton, {*filter*}ia

As a beginner, I still don't understand it all: does this already contain "the" answer? Help appreciated!

Comment: You've added lots of links but you haven't supplied a working example nor said what change you want to make. Make a small document using this environment and if `\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\small}` doesn't do what you want then describe in what way you want it to do something different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right command to act on is indeed `\TPTnoteSettings`, but its standard definition must be preserved, because it contains essential information for typesetting the notes. The best is to add to it and `etoolbox` provides a simple way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}[b]
\caption{A caption}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
42\tnote{1} & some & text & to have room\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Elsewhere I spotted `\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\small\linespread{1}\selectfont}`, though I'm not sure what the `\selectfont` part does: what does it do?"

Comment: using `\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}` would allow me to drop `\small` from the previous comment's code; but what about `\linespread{1}` - where should that be included best? Should that (still) be included, or are there better ways (of making those linespacings narrower)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Add `\linespread{1}` *before* `\footnotesize`.

Comment: @egreg: Unfortunately this does not work in case of using `para` and `flushleft` in `threeparttable's` preamble config. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563750/threeparttable-how-to-change-font-size-of-threeparttables-table-notes-when-als

Answer (score 4):

I used a simpler approach which was adequate for my needs

```
...
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item [1] See \url{https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/}
\end{tablenotes}
...
```

Which was inspired by https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/

FYI: I added the URL in the item note as my table has a series of long URLs I needed to fit within the column width.