# threeparttable - appending commands to \TPTnoteSettings does not work if package called with flushleft option

Tags: tables, fontsize, etoolbox, threeparttable

In the `tablenotes` environment defined by the `threeparttable` package, I wanted to resize my notes globally throughout my document.

I have found this answer to a question somebody posted in regards to a similar problem: [Using `\appto` from the `etoolbox` package to append to `\TPTnoteSettings`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108588/6993).

Now it turns out: this solution does not work if `threeparttable` is invoked with an option such as `flushleft`, see the MWE. The result looks like this (note that the text under the table has the same size as the text in the table):
[image: Unchanged footnote]

Compare this to calling the package without any options or with `[normal]`, which also works:

[image: Small text when package called without option.]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
      \caption{A caption}
      \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        42& some & text & to have room\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item the first note
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work with `\TPT@defaults` (using `\g@addto@macro` you don't need `etoolbox`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\TPT@defaults{\footnotesize} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
      \caption{A caption}
      \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        42& some & text & to have room\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item the first note
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]