# (longtable threeparttablex) table notes font size

Tags: tables, fontsize, longtable

What I need is the font size of table notes being 8pt. Reading the package documentations and the questions here, I as a beginner tried:

```
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\fontsize{8}{9.6}}
```

or `\setTableNoteFont{\scriptsize}` as this would give me an 8pt when using 12pt in my document class.

Another try was working with `etoolbox` like in that [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108588/34092) without success.

Well, changing the table note size to `\scriptsize` manually in the specific table notes of a table worked with `\scriptsize\textit{Anmerkungen.} \lipsum`, but not the setting in the preamble.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6} 

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      

\usepackage{lmodern}         

\usepackage{lipsum}           
\setlipsumdefault{8}          

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}      

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\scriptsize}


\begin{document}


\begin{ThreePartTable}


\begin{longtable}{l r r @{\hskip 0.5in} l r r}          
 \toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Liste 2} \\   \midrule

krankheitsassoziiert & \% & WL & neutral & \% & WL \\[0.5ex]   \midrule

Wort 1        &  5.53   &  12   &   Wort 2  &   7.30    &   12      \\
Wort 3        &  0.25   &   9   &   Wort 4  &   0.21    &   10  \\
Wort 5        &  0.07   &  13   &   Wort 6  &   0.07    &   13  \\ [1ex] 

\bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\begin{tablenotes}

    \textit{Anmerkungen.} \lipsum

    \end{tablenotes}


\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for helping a latex beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123677/34092) I found another suggestion which worked for me. Sorry for the duplicate but I didn't find that topic before...