# Limit Font Size to 10pt in Caption

Tags: captions, fontsize

The styleguide of our faculty states that notes below figures must be in font-size 10pt.

I've skipped over various posts, but none of them answering the specific 10pt solution - only small or ultra-small is given.

My document looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for equations over multiple lines
\usepackage[hang,bottom]{footmisc} % Fußzeile bleibt am Boden %
\usepackage{natbib}  % havard style citation
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{longtable} % table over two pages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} %note below table

\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{theorem}{Definition}[section]




\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.8em}

\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25} % don't modify the low-level parameter \linespread directly
\usepackage{hyperref}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Title:This should be in normal 12pt text size}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption*{Note: This comment should be in  10pt text size}
\end{figure}



\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{This should be in normal 12pt text size}
 \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX (in \%)}\tabularnewline
\hline
A&$1$&$100$\tabularnewline
\text{\quad B}&$  4$&$4.37$\tabularnewline
\text{\quad \quad C}&$   24$&$0.37$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
 \item[]Note: This comment should be in  10pt text size

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you use the caption package where's the problem? See docs.

Comment: The exact font sizes of `\large`, `\small` and so on depend on the document class you are using and on the size specifications you did. A list of font sizes in pt for the `article` class can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/134144

Comment: @leandris: Thanks for the comment! So since I use an article, \thefontsize\small should be fine. But how to use it only in a certain caption*{} or  in the tableoites \begin{tablenotes}?

Comment: @jogi - Not quite: If you use the `article` document class with a main font size of `12pt`, you must execute `\footnotesize` to obtain `10pt`.

Comment: @Mico: So I simply put \footnotesize in front of the text in the caption? Like \caption*{\footnotesize {Note: This comment should be in  10pt text size}}

Comment: This approach will work, but you will need to repeat it for every `\caption*`. There are more automated ways in the following links: For notes below figures this answer might be helpful:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56535/134144. For changing font sizes in tablenotes see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108588/134144

Comment: @lwandris and @ rest  - thanks for your efforts - great community. So putting together - using \footnotesize{} creates 10pt font. May be done manually but automated may be more elegant. If someone post an aswer I can accept it

Comment: @Jogi - Please see the answer I just posted.

Comment: I've also taken the liberty of editing your code, to replace the `center` environments inside the `table` and `figure` floats with `\centering` directives. The big advantage of using `\centering` directives instead of `center` environments is that it helps avoid creating unnecessarily large whitespace gaps around the floats. Separately, I also simplified the options passed to the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using the `article` document class with a main document font size of `12pt`, issuing the directive `\footnotesize` will produce text at a `10pt` size. And, since you're also loading the [caption package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption), you should write

```
...
\begin{table} % or: \begin{figure}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\caption{...} \label{...}
...
\end{table} & or: \end{figure}
...
```

to generate captions typeset at, you guessed it, `10pt`. Note that since the `\captionsetup` directive is issued within a `table` (or `figure`) environment, the scope of this directive is limited to the `table` (or `figure`).

If you wanted to change the caption size *globally* to `10pt`, you should issue the directive

```
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: is there a way to set in pt instead?

Comment: @ZachSmith - Please post a new query. That way, many more people will see than if it's tucked away as a comment on some earlier answer.

Comment: This answer is good - except that I was looking for explicitly setting a size in pts. It would be better if this answer was adjusted to show for sizing in pts (since I found my way here...)

Comment: @ZachSmith - The simple answer is that the `caption` package, as of now, does *not* offer a standard path to setting an absolute font size directly. Personally, I think that's exactly as it should be. Letting users specify arbitrary font sizes for captions is an open invitation to creating dreadful-looking captions. If you're indeed desperate to create such material, I suggest you post a new query.

Answer (score 1):

The following in a MWE that globally sets both, the table notes and the notes below figures to 10pt, while leaving the actual captions of figures and tables at a size of 12pt.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} %note below table

\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\TPT@defaults{\footnotesize} 
\makeatother
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}\caption*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Title:This should be in normal 12pt text size}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\fnote{ Note: This comment should be in  10pt text size}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{This should be in normal 12pt text size}
 \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{XXX (in \%)}\tabularnewline
\hline
A&1&100\tabularnewline
\quad B&  4&4.37\tabularnewline
\quad \quad C&   24&0.37\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
 \item[]Note: This comment should be in  10pt text size

\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```