# threeparttable: How to change font size of threeparttable's table notes when also using flushleft?

Tags: tables, booktabs, threeparttable, tablenotes, tnote

I want to modify the font size of `tnotes` in `threeparttables` based on [this approach of user egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108588/78784).

**Minimum Working Example (MWE) of functional approach:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}% <-- decreases font size of tnote

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}[b]
            \caption{A caption}
            \begin{tabular}{llll}
                \toprule
                Test\tnote{1} & some & text & to have room\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item [1] the first tnote
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

This solution works completely fine as long as I do NOT add `flushleft` into the preamble config of `threeparttable`. As soon as I add this additional config, the upper solution does not work anymore.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE) of non-functional approach:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}% <-- added `para` and `flushleft`
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}% <-- decreases font size of tnote

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{threeparttable}[b]
            \caption{A caption}
            \begin{tabular}{llll}
                \toprule
                Test\tnote{1} & some & text & to have room\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item [1] the first tnote
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Why not just write `\footnotesize` right before `\begin{tablenotes}`?

Comment: @Mico: Because it could surely be defined globally somehow. :-)

Comment: Then how about executing `\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\footnotesize}` in the preamble?

Comment: The problem is how the `flushleft` option is defined, it has a setup macro which when executed overwrites what ever is in `\TPTnoteSettings` instead of adding to it.

Comment: @Mico: Awesome, thank you! Why not posting this as an answer? :-)

Comment: Micos solution is much simpler, as otherwise you'll need to patch like this: `\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\TPT@opt@flushleft}{\def\TPTnoteSettings{\labelsep.2em \leftmargin\z@ \labelwidth\z@}}{\def\TPTnoteSettings{\labelsep.2em \leftmargin\z@ \labelwidth\z@\tiny}}{}{\NOPE}
\makeatother` which is horrible.

Answer (score 3):

Your formatting objective may be achieved robustly by running

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\footnotesize}
```

in the preamble.

A full MWE -- note that it runs both `\smallskip` and `\footnotesize` at the start of each `tablenotes` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft,para]{threeparttable}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\smallskip\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{A caption}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        Test\tnote{1} & some & text & to have room\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[1] The first tnote
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `\footnotesize` to another macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\TPTdoTablenotes{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{threeparttable}[b]
  \caption{A caption}

  \begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule
  Test\tnote{1} & some & text & to have room\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
  \item [1] the first tnote long enough to see at least a line break
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Other than demonstrating advanced knowledge about the inner workings of the `threeparttable` package, are there practical advantages to running `\appto\TPTdoTablenotes{\footnotesize}` instead of `\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\footnotesize}`?

Comment: @Mico I happen to not like `\AtBeginEnvironment`… ;-)